# Unable to get CORSFilter to work

Tags: cors, wildfly

I am trying to implement CORSFilter but am unable to get it to modify the headers. Did I miss something in my implementation? I am using Java7 on WildFly8.

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1">
  <context-param>
    <description>Automatically scan WEB-INF/lib jars and WEB-INF/classes directory for both @Provider and JAX-RS resource classes (@Path, @GET, @POST etc..) and register them.</description>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
      <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
      <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
      <param-value>3600</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Pom entry:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

I have written a filter to do this and it correctly adds the Access-Control-Allow headers but I get nothing from the cors-filter. Can anyone spot what I may have done wrong that it isn't adding the Header entries?

----Update---------
Here is the filter that I wrote which is working:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebFilter(filterName = "HTML5CorsFilter", urlPatterns = {"/resources/api-docs/*"})
public class HTML5CorsFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
      System.out.println("************In the DoFilter method.**************");
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

I would just use this filter except I have been tasked to use com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter. The specifics of what I need this for (initially) is to allow a single swagger ui installation to server multiple application so the headers I am attempting to add are needed on the requests for the swagger jsons.

Answer (score 1):

Servlet filters are for servlets. Are you trying to filter requests to JAX-RS resources? In that case, you should use a `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter`.

I presume (but did not verify) that JAX-RS processing takes over very early in the HTTP request processing pipeline, well before servlet filters kick in.

Comment: I added additional information to my original post. I included the filter I have working. It would be simpler if I could just use that and move on.